# Whole file read when passing a file read stream to readline.createInterface in Node.js

Tags: node.js, fs, readline, node-streams

I'm creating a file read stream on a big file and passing it to `readline.createInterface`. The goal is to, after that, use `for await ... of` to get lines from the file without reading it all to memory.

However, even if I don't read anything, the whole stream seems to be processed. I know this happens because I tried to listen to events (and they were emitted), and also because my script takes a while to finish if I use a really big file.

Is there a way to avoid this behavior? I would like the stream to be consumed on demand.

I can successfully implement this behavior if, instead of using `readline`, I read chunks from the stream and search for the lines myself, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

MWE:

```
var readline = require('readline');
var fs = require('fs');
var file = 'really_big_file.txt'; // 2GB is what I used

readline.createInterface({input: fs.createReadStream(file)});

// this takes a while to finish because the file is being read,
//  even if I'm not doing anything with the stream
```

Answer (score 0):

From official [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_example_read_file_stream_line_by_line) of `readline` package:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

async function processLineByLine() {
  const fileStream = fs.createReadStream('/tmp/input.txt');
  // If you want to start consuming the stream after some point
  // in time then try adding the open even to the readstream
  // and explictly pause it
  fileStream.on('open', () => {
    fileStream.pause();


    // Then resume the stream when you want to start the data flow
    setInterval(() => {
      fileStream.resume();
    }, 1000)
  });

  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fileStream,
    crlfDelay: Infinity
  });
  // Note: we use the crlfDelay option to recognize all instances of CR LF
  // ('\r\n') in input.txt as a single line break.

  for await (const line of rl) {
    // Each line in input.txt will be successively available here as `line`.
    console.log(`Line from file: ${line}`);
  }

  console.log("reading finished");
}

processLineByLine();
```

Try storing the interface in a variable and use it further for iterations. Here what happens is readline starts and continues till since nothing asks it to wait for

Further reading: https://wanago.io/2019/03/04/node-js-typescript-4-paused-and-flowing-modes-of-a-readable-stream/